# rstudio manipulate: how to make a variable picker?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I have a data frame (df) with the following structure:

```
ID TIME VAR1 VAR2
truc 4 2 30
truc 10 4 60
truc 40 6 90
bidule 4 5 12
bidule 10 15 13
bidule 40 45 14
```

I would like to use manipulate to choose which variable (VAR1 or VAR2) to plot.
Here is what I tried:

```
manipulate(
  ggplot(df, aes(x=TIME, y=y.factor, color=ID))+
  geom_point(),
y.factor=picker(VAR1, VAR2)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use characters inside the `picker()` function (names in quotes) and then  inside `ggplot()` call use `aes_string()` because y.factor contains name of variable for y values and not the actual y values. Also see that inside the `aes_string()` names `TIME` and `ID` are in quotes but `y.factor` isn't.

```
manipulate(
      ggplot(df, aes_string(x="TIME", y=y.factor, color="ID"))+
            geom_point(),
      y.factor=picker("VAR1", "VAR2")
)
```